# Use firebase notification with local notifications iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to use firebase notification with local notifications in iOS app 
since I don't have Apple developer account, and I need to do these notifications.
I tried to use observe method, but it does not serve me with what I want. I want to send a notification when ever a child in firebase added as in follow/unfollow

Answer (score 0):

When you doesn’t have an Apple account. You would not be able to create certificates, private key, provisioning profile. Getting notification from firebase certificate with private key is required. So better to get Apple account and create certificates. Then you can move ahead.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't have the money and I am doing it for school project, and i really want to solve this problem

Comment: That’s ok, but without an Apple account, this is not possible. Good luck for your work.